# Font first load as text then load icon

Tags: css, icons

I'm using material.io icons on a site. The first time the site is opened, the icons don't load and remain text; on all future page loads, the icons load properly.

What can I do to make the icons show up the first time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution with this trick:
If I write the `i` tag with following style:

```
<i class="material-icons middle comment"></i>
```

Then when the document is ready I fill the content of `i` tag. I write following jQuery code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('i.person').html("comment");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this situation happened when the css of material.io is loading !
you can use svg for important icon it's make load faster and for another icon use material.io

or use jQuery HTML method to show icons after the document load completely 
exmaple for :

```
<i class="material-icons">&#xE87C;</i>

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('i.material-icons').html("&#xE87C;");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Write your jquery inside

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   //your code comes here
});
```

Code which are under `$(document).ready();` will load when all the necessary actions are completed on page.

Comment: Change the html using jquery or javascript. Hope you know how to do it